# Is it possible to change the order of static imports followed by imports in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, checkstyle

By default, when you use the ctrl + shift + o shortcut, the static imports are placed before the standard imports

```
import static org.mockito.Maters.any;
import static org.mockito.Maters.anyInt;
import static org.mockito.Maters.anyString;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
```

Unfortunately, this is against our company's internal code checkstyle, is it possible to change this grouping so the static imports come after the standard imports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure the order of imports in the Preferences in the 'Java > Code Style > Organize Imports' page. This will allow you to specify the order of static and normal imports (and a lot more if you want).

Comment: Thank you, that's working great. Little annoying you have to add each package individually, instead of *all* static imports, but there's only a few static packages we use so I can live with it.

Comment: You can use '*' to to match everything that isn't in a specific rule.

Comment: Also note that you can Import and Export this list so you can give a standard list to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I have found one solution.
Change the file .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs and put new line:

```
    org.eclipse.jdt.ui.importorder=com;java;javax;org;;\#;
```

And you will have:
java.*
javax.*
org.*
<others>
import static *